# running queries for multiple tables in one query if value existed on first table

Tags: php, sql, pdo

right now i have the following table structure and query which I would think is a bad practice and puts heavier load on server than it should, here's the table structure with the columns used or needed for the query:

`tbl1 :`

```
id : int (primary key)
customer : varchar
license : int (fk_license --> tbl2)
```

`tbl2:`

```
license : int
count : int
```

now, whenever i have to delete a data from `tbl` I want to decrease the count from `tbl2` by 1. Right now I'm running multiple queries

```
SELECT license FROM tbl1 WHERE id = $x
//then storing license as a var, lets say $license for example

DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE id = $x
UPDATE tbl2 SET count = count - 1 WHERE license = $license
```

I'm using PDO and binding params but for simplicity just putting out the sql queries as simple here as possible.

My question is can I perform these operations in one trip to the database? or at least twice if not once?

Comment: Why do u need to maintain the count in seperate table, you can just do a select count(*) from first table>
There is no need for second table

Comment: lets say the tables are not as simple as they look, I just put out few of the used columns in here, in reality tbl2 itself has around 27 columns and tbl1 is much larger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use trigger in such case.

Step 1 Change delimiter:

```
delimiter $$
```

Step 2 Create trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `reduce_count`     
  AFTER DELETE ON `tbl1`     
  FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN
  UPDATE tbl2 SET count = count - 1 WHERE license =  OLD.license ;
END
$$
```

Step 3 Restore delimiter:

```
delimiter ;
```

**UPDATED**: I create similar table per you described, 
T3 like table1 and t4 like table2.
On deleting from t3, count from t4 was reduced.
[image]

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' - what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I just tried to create the trigger from the phpmyadmin sql section here, isnt that how triggers are supposed to be created? I havent dealt with triggers and events in phpmyadmin before sorry if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: yup but phpmyadmin's interface and usage is new to me

Comment: I tried the usual trigger creation method and heres what I got: #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: You need trigger rights, to access this. 

I have created this trigger and it works fine. Updating answer

Comment: yeah, the trigger was right I guess I just do not have the previlige. Thanks for the help I will try and ask the server admins to get me the right.